# How to display the values from multidiamentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here i have one array, from here i want display all values, but don't know how get all values from this array,i am new person of development any one know means please update my code.I spent lot of time but i am not able to find the exact answer

```
print_r($planMaster);

{
"status": "success",
"message": "Total 3 record(s) found.",
"total_record": 3,
"data": [
    {
        "planId": "1",
        "planName": "Easy Plan",
        "createdOn": "2017-10-23 15:17:08",
        "createdBy": "Kani",
        "updatedOn": "0000-00-00",
        "updatedBy": "",
        "planDescription": [
            {
                "descriptionId": "1",
                "planId": "1",
                "plandescTitle": "Contacts details up to",
                "plandescResult": "24"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "2",
                "planId": "1",
                "plandescTitle": "Bonus Contact details up to",
                "plandescResult": "2"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "3",
                "planId": "1",
                "plandescTitle": "Area Master Assistance",
                "plandescResult": "No"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "4",
                "planId": "1",
                "plandescTitle": "Contact details through sms",
                "plandescResult": "Yes"
            }
        ],
        "planValue": [
            {
                "pvId": "2",
                "planId": "1",
                "startDate": "2017-10-23",
                "endDate": "2017-10-30",
                "planValue": "1000"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "planId": "2",
        "planName": "Cool Plan",
        "createdOn": "2017-10-23 16:58:32",
        "createdBy": "Kani",
        "updatedOn": "0000-00-00",
        "updatedBy": "",
        "planDescription": [
            {
                "descriptionId": "5",
                "planId": "2",
                "plandescTitle": "Contact details up to",
                "plandescResult": "48"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "6",
                "planId": "2",
                "plandescTitle": "Bonus Contact details up to",
                "plandescResult": "4"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "7",
                "planId": "2",
                "plandescTitle": "Area Master Assistance",
                "plandescResult": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "8",
                "planId": "2",
                "plandescTitle": "Contact details through sms",
                "plandescResult": "Yes"
            }
        ],
        "planValue": [
            {
                "pvId": "3",
                "planId": "2",
                "startDate": "2017-10-23",
                "endDate": "2017-10-30",
                "planValue": "2000"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "planId": "3",
        "planName": "Free Plan",
        "createdOn": "2017-10-23 17:09:20",
        "createdBy": "Kani",
        "updatedOn": "0000-00-00",
        "updatedBy": "",
        "planDescription": [
            {
                "descriptionId": "9",
                "planId": "3",
                "plandescTitle": "Contacts details up to",
                "plandescResult": "5"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "10",
                "planId": "3",
                "plandescTitle": "Area Master Assistance",
                "plandescResult": "No"
            },
            {
                "descriptionId": "11",
                "planId": "3",
                "plandescTitle": "Contact details through sms",
                "plandescResult": "Yes"
            }
        ],
        "planValue": [
            {
                "pvId": "4",
                "planId": "3",
                "startDate": "2017-10-23",
                "endDate": "2017-10-30",
                "planValue": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Expected Answer

```
Plan Name: Easy Plan


    plandescTitle: Contacts details up to
     plandescResult: 24

     plandescTitle: Bonus Contact details up to
     plandescResult": 2
```

I tried like this but not getting answer

```
 <?php
      $planMaster =  GetResponse($API_URL.'getplan_Master');
      if (!empty($planMaster)) {                           
      foreach ($planMaster['data'] as $result) {
      ?>  
          <th><?php echo $result['planName']; ?> 1000/-</th>


            <?php
            foreach ($planMaster['planDescription'] as $descresult) {
                echo $descresult['plandescTitle'];
            }

            ?>

     <?php
      }
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'll explain it if it works.

```
 <?php
      $planMaster =  GetResponse($API_URL.'getplan_Master');
      if (!empty($planMaster)) {                           
      foreach ($planMaster['data'] as $result) {
      ?>  
          <th><?php echo $result['planName']; ?> 1000/-</th>


            <?php
            foreach ($result['planDescription'] as $descresult) {
                echo $descresult['plandescTitle'];
            }

            ?>

     <?php
      }
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use json_decode() function to convert json data to php Array

```
 $planMaster =  GetResponse($API_URL.'getplan_Master');
 $planMasterArray = json_decode($planMaster, true);
 if (isset($planMasterArray) && is_array($planMasterArray)) {                           
    foreach ($planMasterArray['data'] as $result) {
    ?>  
      <th><?php echo $result['planName']; ?> 1000/-</th>
        <?php
        foreach ($planMaster['planDescription'] as $descresult) {
            echo $descresult['plandescTitle'];
        }
        ?>
   <?php
    }
  }
?>
```